# How to enter values if i dont know the number and type

Tags: java, types, field

I want user to enter fields with their types and later fill them. Types can be diffent like int, string, double etc. How can I create a method/constructor that will allow to enter values to these fields?
I don't know how to make it, because the number and type of these fields are unknown so I can not create fields in normal way like:

```
String name;
int age;
```

Should I use any List or Map, there are many of these and I cant figure it out.

Comment: To me it is very unclear what you're actually after. Could you provide some more examples and elaborate on what you're after in the end? I have the feeling this could be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: First user enters number of fields that he wants to have, then their names and types e.g name as string, age as int etc. then the app asks him to enter values to the fields he created and i want to have methods to set/get  these fields as well

Comment: use an Object map. use the field names as key and value as value. the only thing would be, that you ignore the datatype

Comment: You should rethink your design. What are you trying to accomplish? A user can enter some random gibberish and you will store it for some reason? What? Java deliberately has a strict typing system which is designed *to help you*. You should not try and get around it for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is another type called object and you can enter any types within object. Here below my:

public class deneme {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    Object object=scanner.next();
    System.out.println(object);

}
```

}
It works nice, I hope you meant this.